# Alocar um vetor dentro de uma função

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Estou com dificuldade de alocar um vetor dentro de uma função, não sei se estou acessando o vetor do jeito certo dentro da função.

**Esse é o código da atividade**
tenho que escrever o código aqui dentro

```
// 8) A funcao deve uma alocar um array com 10 posicoes e
// inicializa-las com o identificador da sua posição
void aloca_array(int** arr) {
}
```

**Esse é o que eu estou fazendo**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// 8) A funcao deve uma alocar um array com 10 posicoes e
// inicializa-las com o identificador da sua posição
void aloca_array(int** arr) {
    *arr = (int*)new int[10];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = i;}  //Linha 11
}


//Codigo principal para testar a função
int main(){
    
    int *array;
    aloca_array(&array);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << array[i] <<" ";}

    return 0;
}
```

Na linha 11 está aparecendo o erro " invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nesse caso, como a variável **arr** é um "ponteiro para ponteiro", é necessário *desreferenciar* o ponteiro para ter acesso ao seu valor. É possível fazer isso acrescentando um * antes da declaração da variável na linha 11. Dessa forma, acredito que o seguinte trecho resolva seu problema:

```cpp
void aloca_array(int** arr) {
    *arr = (int*)new int[10];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        (*arr)[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Fonte: [Docs Microsoft - Raw Pointers](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp)